# Can custom classes be moved to their own library?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to be able to re-use some functionality across applications. In this case, I'm trying to create a wrapper for MongoDb. So I created the following class:

```
/** MongoDb
  * Parms
  *   apiKey - This is the api key of the account being used
  *   dbName - This is the name of the database we are connecting to
  */
function MongoDb(apiKey, dbName) {
  this.dbName = dbName;
  this.baseUrl = "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/"+this.dbName;
  this.options = {
    "contentType":"application/json",
    "method":"get" // default
  };
  this.apiKey = "apiKey="+apiKey;
}

MongoDb.prototype = {
  constructor: MongoDb,
  getCollections: function(dbName) {
    var url = this.baseUrl + "/collections?" + this.apiKey;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, this.options);
    return JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  }
}
```

I then created the following function to test it:

```
function test() {
  var db = new MongoDb("xxxxxxxxx", "yyyyyyy");
}
```

This works exactly as expected. So given that success, I moved it off to its own library and now my test script is giving me the error: `TypeError: Imported script is not a function, it is object. (line 2, file "MongoTest")` I can't turn up anyone else getting this error in my searches.

Is this unsupported, or is there another way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import a library into a script, you have to give it a name, by the default it's then library own name. So, if you named the library "MonboDb" you should do:

```js
function test() {
  var db = new MongoDb.MongoDb("xxxxxxxxx", "yyyyyyy");
}
```

Just to clarify, you could've named the library (when importing it in the script) simply as "Lib", then you'd do:

```js
function test() {
  var db = new Lib.MongoDb("xxxxxxxxx", "yyyyyyy");
}
```

Conclusion, moving any code to a library adds a new "namespace" to the code. This is the correct and expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm just learning the nuances of Google Script.